# Reference frame as a $(1,1)$-tensor field $R$ with $R^2=R$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spacetime, tensor-calculus

In a paper about the splitting of the space-time [for reference "THE STRUCTURE OF SPACE–TIME: RELATIVITY GROUPS" (International Journal of Geometric Methods in Modern Physics Vol. 3, No. 3 (2006) 591–603)], it identifies the *reference frame* with a $(1,1)$-tensor field $R\in\mathcal{T}^1_1(M)$, $M$ is the space-time, and satisfying the condition $R^2=R$. For convenience, it decompose $R$ into the tensor product of a vector field $\Gamma$ and a one-form $\alpha$
$$R=\alpha \otimes \Gamma$$
and the requirement $R^2=R$ is equivalent to the condition $\alpha[\Gamma]=1$.

My question is: how do I prove this last equivalence? I have no clue about how to compute $R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $(1,1)$-tensor of the form $\alpha\otimes v$ eats a vector $x$ and spits out the vector $\alpha(x) v$, where $\alpha(x)$ is just a number.  If you feed the result to $\alpha\otimes v$ again, you'll get the answer you're looking for.